# Asp.net Core 1.1 HttpGet FromQuery complex model binding not working

Tags: asp.net, model-binding, asp.net-core-1.1

Having this model:

```
public class PagingParameters
{
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

Using the following controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public object Query([FromQuery] PagingParameters query)
{
    return null;
}
```

Sending the following data:
[image]

Model data still won't properly bind:
[image]

Is there something missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a *dictionary*, not an object. In other words, instead of `query[PageIndex]`, you need `query.PageIndex`, or simply just `PageIndex`.